# Need to decrement counter in parent thread when child thread ends

Tags: pthreads

I am using pthreads to write a cli/server program.  The server will establish a connection with and create a separate thread for each connection to process.  Once each session ends I would like to inform main server process that the connection has ended.
I am not sure what is the best way to inform parent thread that the child thread has ended.
I am new to this so still not

Answer (score 0):

Pass into the threads a function/event/delegate to call when the client<>server thread terminates.  In the function/event/delegate/whatever, use some inter-thread comms mechanism to signal the 'main server process'.  Exactly how you do that depends on what the 'main server process' normally waits on for input.

Comment: Martin thank you for your answer but I am not clear on certain things.
I am considering using IPC to do this, but from what i understand there are many different IPC methods such as; signals, mmapping, semaphore, pipes...etc.
I am not sure which is best for what I need to do.
I was also not sure by what you mean by passing function to thread, can you elaborate please.